# Wanting to make a repeating task for SQLite database

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

I'm currently using a database that has tables, one of which has hundreds of ids, and I need to add something to a list of them.

This is also failing to actually insert them into the database, which is frustrating. I'm still a beginner, which is probably obvious from my code.

```
INSERT INTO card_card_categories (id, card_id, card_category_id, num, created_at, updated_at)
    SELECT
        id * 1000 AS id,
        id AS card_id, 
        1412 AS card_category_id, 
        85 AS num, 
        created_at, 
        updated_at
    FROM
        cards
    WHERE
        id = 100994
```

This is my current SQL insert statement. This is good for 1 at a time, but I haven't been able to find a way to make it so I can enter multiple ids at once and have it fill it in as if I put them in one at a time.

Is this possible, if so how?

Comment: are  1412 AS card_category_id, 
        85 AS num,  going to change for every id?

Comment: No, those say the exact same for all of them, as it's an unused number on every one.

Comment: one of which has hundreds of ids - which one?

Comment: Assuming card_card_categories is the 'one which has hunreds of ids' Is there some reason that you wish to insert for id = 100994 that can be converted to a logical expression? For example card_card_categories doesn't have an entry where id * 1000 is true? –

Comment: So, heres exactly what im doing. I want to add the category value 1412  with 85 as the num to about 255 different IDs, each of these has a 1 and 0 on the end of it. Example numbers of this are 101007 101006 and 101139. I am trying to figure out a method where i can do all of these IDs at once, or in larger bursts (Larger being about 10-20) This way i dont have to manually add 2 rows and fill it out for each one. Is there something i can do to complete this task, or am i fresh outta luck

Comment: All of the ids need to be higher than the ones before them, which is why that contains the * 1000 expression, to keep the ids before the card ids from conflicting.

Comment: 'each of these has a 1 and 0 on the end of it' ?  which end and why do none of your examples fit this rule?

Comment: it would be generating the c.id of 1010071 and 1010070. the normal id would be different for the 1010071 from the 1010070

Comment: If it isn't known, this is a SQLite serverless database. I probably should've clarified that.

Comment: Your code obviously inserts 1 row. If you remove the where clause don't you get what you want?

Comment: I'm attempting to add 1 row for each ID, however it isnt inserting the row and I can't get it to insert more than 1 ID at a time.

Comment: *it isnt inserting the row* why? What error do you get?

Comment: That's whats confusing me, it's not an error.
Result: query executed successfully. Took 0ms, 0 rows affected
At line 1:
When i check the db, nothing has changed, even after refreshing. It's the exact same.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. Your query without the WHERE clause should insert in `card_card_categories` as many rows as there are in `cards`.

Answer (score 0):

Cody, your query CAN NOT work as you confuse the column 'id' (the real ID) with a "virtual" column name 'id' which holds values 1000x bigger than the original value.

As you multiply each 'real' id by 1000, there is NO value which can end in 994 ! So the WHERE clause will fail every time - hence the "0 rows affected" message.

Try rewriting your query as :

```
INSERT INTO card_card_categories (id, card_id, card_category_id, num, created_at, updated_at)
    SELECT
        id * 1000 AS id_1000,
        id AS card_id, 
        1412 AS card_category_id, 
        85 AS num, 
        created_at, 
        updated_at
    FROM
        cards
    WHERE
        card_id = 100994
```

Comment: actually mine worked. I just realized that my ids needed to have a 1 and 0 added to the end of them. I was making rows that didnt match the ids i meant to add. So no, it worked exactly the way i wanted it to, i was just being dumb.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by using a python script that just repeated the process with my ids, so this was easily resolved, i was just being foolish.